# Can I index nested documents on ElasticSearch without mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document whose structure changes often, how can I index nested documents inside it without changing the mapping on ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index documents in Elasticsearch without providing a mapping yes.

However, Elasticsearch makes a decision about the type of a field when the first document contains a value for that field. If you add document 1 and it has a field called item_code, and in document 1 item_code is a string, Elasticsearch will set the type of field "item_code" to be string. If document 2 has an integer value in item_code Elasticsearch will have already set the type as string.

Basically, field type is index dependant, not document dependant.

This is mainly because of Apache Lucene and the way it handles this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a case where some data structure changes, while other doesn't, you could use an object type, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html.

You can even go as far as to use "enabled": false on it, which makes elasticsearch just store the data. You couldn't search it anymore, but maybe you actually don't even want that?